# Java Servlet for Google Action is not working, logs giving manifest error

Tags: java, gradle, servlets, intellij-idea, actions-on-google

Okay, so I am working from a boilerplate to get a basic Google Action to work. It's entirely coded in Java and Gradle, and when uploading to Gcloud, it is successful. Only problem now is that my webhook initializes and runs, however, it returns this error in the logs on run:

```
2019-01-20 04:04:52 default[20190119t230217]  no main manifest attribute, in app.jar
```

Now, I know that that error code means that there isn't a main-class defined in the Java files, but there shouldn't be, because it's supposed to be a servlet... I think? It's been included in the DialogFlow console as well. So, what should I do to resolve this error?

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA

OS: Mac OS

Full log: https://pastebin.com/e4DeBDJz

Additional files for viewing are on my github repo here: https://github.com/TrianReallyHard/HabiticaAction

Comment: Do you get the same message if you build project from command line using Gradle?

Comment: Let me check. I'll get back to you with the results.

Comment: @y.bedrov Same result after compiling from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this question, as I am an idiot. Turns out I accidentally package protected the action handler file, thus making the servlet unable to see the it.